# Facebook Logout SDK

Tags: php, facebook

i have created my facebook application,i use `$this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();` to logout a user,but it will causes facebook.com logout too..

so any idea to prevent this?

Comment: Wont that be against facebook.com policies ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logout

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to search and read similar threads?

[Facebook Oauth Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764436/facebook-oauth-logout)
[Facebook php SDK getLogoutUrl() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760680/facebook-php-sdk-getlogouturl-problem)

Because afaik you

- Don't have to logout user from application which runs as facebook page/app
- You shouldn't log out user on Facebook, if you are using oAuth to let him login to your website with his facebook account

Comment: i need to logout user, because another user can be loggedin

Comment: so edit your question and provide more about how it works, because this sounds like an application logic problem.

Comment: i just want to logout the web application, just like javascript SDK, but i want in php way.

Comment: so users are logging to your website via facebook?

Comment: Wont that be against facebook.com policies ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#logout

Comment: @user01 it's very old question, probably policy changed since then

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a problem in new version of PHP Sdk, and

```
 $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

not working,

you can try it to set other file logout.php in that you have to start session and then destroy it..

logout.php

```
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
```

it's working, i use it.