# Legacy Facebook connect logout, how to avoid "You are logging out of both this site and Facebook" prompt

Tags: facebook

Whenever I use FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect or FB.Connect.Logout functions from Facebook library, they give prompt "You are logging out of both this site and Facebook". Is there any way to suppress this dialogue from  showing up?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this using those functions and won't be as they have deprecated that library.  The new facebook javascript sdk has [Fb.logout()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) which doesn't have the dialog. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764436/facebook-oauth-logout) has other possible alternatives, such as redirecting the user to:

http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?api_key=xxxxx&session_key=xxxx&next=http://yourwebsite.com