# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow, how to clear user cache?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an extension that works with Gmail and I'd like to be able to allow users to switch between Gmail accounts and still make use of the Google REST APIs.

I'm using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow to acquire OAuth2 access tokens to the Google APIs.

This workflow opens a modal sort of chrome webview. With no url bar at the top. Upon entering a username and password the first time, then allowing for the requested scopes, the webview closes. My app then receives the redirect URI with the access token included. Great.

The problem comes when switching users. One would think it would be as simple as checking that a new email is logged in, then doing the chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow again to grab a new token.

Unfortunately the first logged in user seems to remain cached in the system.

```
function webAuthFlow(userEmail, forceApprovalPrompt, xhrCallback) {
  var baseUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
  var forceApprovalPrompt = forceApprovalPrompt || 'auto';
  var urlParams = {
    'redirect_uri' : 'https://inobjcmbajbmllkgkigemcfnikdmlidn.chromiumapp.org/callback',
    'response_type' : 'token',
    'client_id' : 'not shown here',
    'scope' : 'https://mail.google.com/ https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/',
    'approval_prompt' : 'force',
    'include_granted_scopes' : 'true'
  };

  var providerDetails = {
    url : baseUrl + '?' + stringify(urlParams),
    interactive : true
  }
  var xhrCallback = xhrCallback || false;
  console.log(xhrCallback);
  var callback = function(responseUrl) {
    var params = {}, 
    queryString = responseUrl.split('#')[1],
    regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g,
    m,
    validateUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo'
    while (m = regex.exec(queryString)) {
      params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
    }
    validateToken(params.access_token, function() { storeToken(params.access_token, userEmail) }, xhrCallback);
  };
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(providerDetails, callback);
};
```

I've tried to inspect the chrome webview that pops up by setting approval_prompt to 'force'. It appears there are some cookies associated with it. I'd like to know how to clear persistent data from the webview.

The only thing that seems to work is completely closing out chrome. Not an acceptable UX for my extension.

Thanks in advance if anyone has any pointers on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I log out of a chrome.identity oauth provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080632/how-do-i-log-out-of-a-chrome-identity-oauth-provider)

Comment: Yeah, removeCachedAuthToken() seems to have no effect on tokens obtained through launchWebAuthFlow. I think the question stands.

Comment: So does the "answer" from the comment - known bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the followings:

- Remove the access token from the token cache
- Remove the user's account preferences
- Remove the user from all auth flows

Then you can use one of the following 2 ways:

1. Remove all auth tokens by using this line of code

   ```
   chrome.identity.clearAllCachedAuthTokens(() => undefined)
   ```
2. Remove each auth token individually. For more info, take a look at this reference: [removeCachedAuthToken](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-removeCachedAuthToken)

   ```
   chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(
      details: InvalidTokenDetails,
      callback?: function,
   )
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Use `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(object details, function callback)` method.

> Removes an OAuth2 access token from the Identity API's token cache.
>
> If an access token is discovered to be invalid, it should be passed to removeCachedAuthToken to remove it from the cache. The app may then retrieve a fresh token with getAuthToken.

Comment: Have you read the comments to the question? This does not currently work: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328876