# How can I log out of Facebook when using OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I have a RoR app using omniauth. I want to allow the user to log out so that they can sign in with a different Facebook user, but no matter what I do, once a user logs into FB, it keeps them logged in.

I have tried:
    https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=&access_token=

To no avail. I also tried the reauth option for omniauth-facebook but that resulted in the user being brought to FB rather than to my specified redirect URL.

Comment: You might want to give this a shot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764436/facebook-oauth-logout

Comment: I am not currently using the FB javascript API and I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, add this to your javascript initialization code: (after FB.init)

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
        FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');
        setTimeout('document.location.reload()',0);
      });
```

And the button of sign out:

```
<a href="/" onclick="FB.logout();">Logout</a>
```

Using the approach  https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=&access_token= will make your user leave your page, as facebook won't redirect to your website again.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: hello, did you fix your problem?